# Yamaha tenor recorder

Tags: recorder

Playing very low notes tend to be an octave too high and I'm blowing very gently. Very new at this and am not sure what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: So what you mean is: _very low notes come out as overblown, despite very gentle blowing_?

Answer (score 5):

If your low notes are coming out an octave too high, and you are blowing very gently, then the most likely problem is that one or more of the fingerholes is not completely closed.  You must make sure your fingers are not allowing any air to leak at all, which is difficult to do and requires practice.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same experience with my Aulos tenor recorder. You really don't have to blow much harder to get an overblown octave. I also found that the angle of the stream of air is important so make sure the position of the beak in your mouth is right. Also make sure that all your finger holes are properly closed, especially your right ring finger that closes the double hole. If you are having trouble closing it, try adjusting the position of your foot joint so that you can comfortably reach the key and the double hole without any discomfort. Lastly, give yourself time to experiment and you'll figure it out. Practise for very short amounts of time at first because your fingers get tired and it's almost impossible to play then.

It took me about a week to be able to reliably play a bottom C. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting the pitch in the wrong register, the classic mistake is a leak at the thumb hole.  Deliberately leaking the thumb hole is how one gets the upper register, and beginners often have trouble covering it accurately, not least because its on the underside of the instrument where you can't see it, and the thumb is less touch-sensitive than the other finger tips.